Expected queue length in various queueing models
Is there a resource, or could someone list out the expected queue length ($L_q$) in each type of queue model with a server capacity: M/M/c; M/D/c; G/G/c; G/D/c; G/M/c

Fro steady state, presuming there is a steady state? What kind of result are you expecting to see for "G (general (independent) arrival or service time)"? Maybe certain specific distributions other than exponential or deterministic?
